# How can I resolve "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' " - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6yOC.png)Ran into "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'" on the following code

static extractText(VisionText visionText) {
String text = '';

```
for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {
  for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
    for (TextElement word in line.elements) {
      text = text + word.text + ' ';
    }
    text = text + '\n';
  }
}

return text;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'"

This error happens when a non-null `String` value is expected, but a nullable `String?` is provided instead.

In this case, if your `text` is a non-null `String` and your `word.text` is a nullable `String?`, you can do this:

```dart
text += (word?.text ?? '') + ' ';
```

Here, the `?.` operator is for checking if `word` is not null, then get the `text` value. `??` is in case `word?.text` is null, then take an empty string as the value. Thus the value is always a non-null one.

You can read more on the [documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) here.

Comment: @MayankShekhar Can you mark mine as the accepted answer, much appreciated! ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
text = text + (word?.text ?? '' ) + ' ';
```